# Polygon not matching world street map in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, polygon

I have a polygon layer that is not matching the World Street map by a few hundred meters in ArcMap. How can I correct this? I have tried projecting the polygon shapefile to WGS 1984 and WGS_1984_Web_Mercator Auxiliary Sphere but with both, I get: ERROR 000151: The geotransformation is not valid.
[image]

Comment: List of transformations you can find saved in your disc in path:

>...\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\Documentation\geographic_transformations.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to re-project your shapefile.  You can apply a [geographic transformation](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002828) to the Data Frame and the data will 'project-on-the-fly'.  If it is still not aligning, the shapefile may have it's coordinate system defined incorrectly.  You may then want to clear the coordinate system (delete the .prj file if it's a shapefile) and then try [determining what the correct coordinate sytem](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/identifying-an-unknown-coordinate-system.htm) is.